# Find nested object that contains a value

Tags: javascript, loops, filter

I have an object containing multiple other objects, inside these nested objects is an array containing multiple objects, each with a `uid`. I'm trying to loop over the objects and find the object that contains a particular `uid`.

My data looks like this

```
const data = {
  "3c5671fde44f44f9ad59d59eb810d87e": {
    "heading": "Heading 1",
    "items": [
      {
        "content": {
          "uid": "4fcd5f4af7a448d48463d4e0a11297d9"
        }
      },
      {
        "content": {
          "uid": "31f975440a0a431592e127b2891cd142"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "ea80e8315b554c9bb40958a6cacf4b0c": {
    "heading": "Heading 2",
    "items": [
      {
        "content": {
          "uid": "d6de8db4c2a74da6915a44d3964277d6"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The `uid` I want to search for is `d6de8db4c2a74da6915a44d3964277d6` when found I want to return it's parent object so I can access the `heading` property.

Current code looks like this but it doesn't work, it's been a long day so I'm likely missing something really simple.

```
const currentUid = "d6de8db4c2a74da6915a44d3964277d6";

const currentHeading = Object.keys(data).forEach(section => {
  return data[section].items.filter(item => {
    return item.content.uid === currentUid;
  });
});
```

When debugging it successfully evaluates to `true` when it finds the correct `uid`, it just doesn't return anything.

Any help welcome!

Comment: Replace `forEach` with `find` and `filter` with `some` then `currentHeading` will be the key of your object from `data`. You can access that object via `data[currentHeading]`

Comment: As simple as that! If you post it as an answer I'll accept it, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`forEach` is meant just for looping the array, use `find` to find the key of your object from `Object.keys(data)`. And inside the callback use `some` instead of `filter` to check the existance. This solution will result in either the key of the object or `null`. To get the object, just check that a key is returned and then use that key to get the object:

```
const currentHeadingKey = Object.keys(data).find(section => {
  return data[section].items.some(item => {
    return item.content.uid === currentUid;
  });
});

const currentHeading = currentHeadingKey != null ? data[currentHeadingKey] : null;
```

`currentHeading` is now either the whole object if found, `null` otherwise. You can access the `heading` property of that object.

**Note:** Since the callbacks of both `find` and `some` have only one statement in them, you can use the implicit return of arrow function to shorten the code:

```
const currentHeadingKey = Object.keys(data).find(section =>
    data[section].items.some(item => item.content.uid === currentUid)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the `Object.values()` method instead, to extract the "parent heading" for the supplied `uid`.

Taking this approach, you can iterate the values of `data`, and filter those `section` values that contain `items` matching the `uid`. In the answer below, this is done via:

```
return items.some(item => item.content.uid === currentUid)
```

Finally, you can `map()` the filtered sections to acquire the corresponding heading(s) of section with matching `uid` items:

```js
function findHeading(data, uid) {
  
  return Object.values(data).filter(section => {

    // Find any item with matching uid in this section, filter this section accordingly
    return section.items.some(item => item.content.uid === currentUid)
  })
  .map(section => {

    // Map heading from any sections matching item uid 
    return section.heading
  });
}

const data = {
"3c5671fde44f44f9ad59d59eb810d87e": {"heading": "Heading 1","items": [{"content": {"uid": "4fcd5f4af7a448d48463d4e0a11297d9"}},{"content": {"uid": "31f975440a0a431592e127b2891cd142"}}]},"ea80e8315b554c9bb40958a6cacf4b0c": {"heading": "Heading 2","items": [{"content": {"uid": "d6de8db4c2a74da6915a44d3964277d6"}}]}
}

const currentUid = "d6de8db4c2a74da6915a44d3964277d6";

console.log(findHeading(data, currentUid))
```

Comment: Why build an array with `filter()` when you just want a boolean that you can get with `some()`?

Comment: @MarkMeyer thanks for that - no reason besides inheriting it from OP. Will update to `some()`